# add/remove fields in django forms

Tags: django, forms, post

So I have a form where user can post "Parents" details also fields for Children from a different model.

What I need is that to allow users to add "Children" fields as many children as they have . Also for the children fields not to be required in case they do not have children.

But, if one of the children fields is filled the others are required.

**models.py** :

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250)


class Kid(models.Model):
    family = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

**views.py**

```
def add_family(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        parent_form = ParentForm(request.POST)
        kid_form = KidForm(request.POST)
        if parent_form.is_valid() and kid_form.is_valid():
            parent = parent_form.save(commit=False)
            parent.save()
            kid = kid_form.save(commit=False)
            kid.family = parent
            kid.save()
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        parent_form = ParentForm()
        kid_form = KidForm()
        template = 'add_family.html'
        context = {'parent_form': parent_form, 'kid_form': kid_form}
        return render(request, template, context)
```

**template**:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ parent_form.title }}
    {{ parent_form.address }}
    {{ kid_form.title }}
    {{ kid_form.age }}
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

so if the "kid_form.title" is filled. then the age is required.

any help?

Comment: I think it is better to solve such dynamic form submission on front end then on back end. And after post make final validation on back end

Comment: can you explain more? Thank you

Comment: lets say you want validation that depends on user selection on front end. If one field is filled then another become required. So Such validation could be performed on front end, not to make user wait until you check all of that on back end. For back end such validation could be checked in `clean` method.

Comment: You might find [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/), and in particular [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) helpful.

Comment: Exactly. I want it to be in the front end. I actually tried a javascript code but didn't work. it was suppose to allow users to add/remove fields for kids with X maximum of times. unfortunately for some reason the fields showed up on the template as tags. e.g : {{ kid_form.title }}. instead of the fields. so that was a fail!

Comment: I've never used formsets nor I know how. I feel like doing it dynamically is better and cleaner. I will check out formsets if i have to eventually . Thank you